# How to use comparison operator for numeric string in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I have an employee table which has field like experience with `VARCHAR` type, this field combines both total year and total month separated by dash (-), so I have to filter experience by year who has more than 3 years experience.

My table structure:

[image]

So now I have to get more than 3 years experienced id's.
I tried like below,

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE experience LIKE '>=3%';
```

I know comparison operator will not support for string but I do not have any new solution for that. Is there any solution?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but can you try: `SELECT experience,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(experience,'-',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num FROM employee WHERE num LIKE '>=3%';`

Comment: Oh sorry, you probebly want to remove the `%` at the end there. My bad.

Comment: My regex solution was not easy, I think SQL regexes are not easy to use and strong like regular regex implementations. Therefore, using a regex for this problem is not practical. I deleted my answer. Maybe you should try strcmp() as jcomeau_ictx explained?

Comment: My solution didn't work either. I can get it to return the number but for some reason I can't use LIKE on it. So ye, I guess jcomeau_ictx solution is the best.

Comment: @icecub - Yes i will try your query, i got easy and best solution from jcomeau_ictx.

Comment: Don't. It doesn't work. I'm trying to figure it out myself. Will let you know if I can get it to work.

Comment: any solution that does numeric comparisons on strings is bound to be hacky and breakable. that said, I fixed the glaring error in my first attempt. sorry about that.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx I absolutely agree. That's why I was converting it to an integer in the first place. But I guess `num` inside my query is still considdered a string somehow.

Comment: Btw I've already updated it to `SELECT experience,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(experience,'-',1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num FROM employee WHERE @num >= 3;`. It no longer returns errors, but doesn't return data either. As said: `num` is probebly a string somehow.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx I've turned my query into a question here and it gave me a great explationation on how to get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460315/how-to-compare-a-user-set-variable-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better answer based on converting to number:

`select * from employee where cast(substring(experience, 1, instr(experience, '-')-1) as signed) >= 3;`

```
mysql> select cast(substring('11-3', 1, instr('11-3', '-')-1) as signed);
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| cast(substring('11-3', 1, instr('11-3', '-')-1) as signed) |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                         11 |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select cast(substring('11-3', 1, instr('11-3', '-')-1) as signed) > 3;
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| cast(substring('11-3', 1, instr('11-3', '-')-1) as signed) > 3 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                              1 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select cast(substring('11-3', 1, instr('11-3', '-')-1) as signed) >= 3;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| cast(substring('11-3', 1, instr('11-3', '-')-1) as signed) >= 3 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                               1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select cast(substring('3-0', 1, instr('3-0', '-')-1) as signed) >= 3;
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| cast(substring('3-0', 1, instr('3-0', '-')-1) as signed) >= 3 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                             1 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select cast(substring('2-11', 1, instr('2-11', '-')-1) as signed) >= 3;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| cast(substring('2-11', 1, instr('2-11', '-')-1) as signed) >= 3 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                               0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select cast(substring('22-11', 1, instr('22-11', '-')-1) as signed) >= 3; 
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cast(substring('22-11', 1, instr('22-11', '-')-1) as signed) >= 3 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                 1 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select cast(substring('11-0', 1, instr('11-0', '-')-1) as signed) >= 3; 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| cast(substring('11-0', 1, instr('11-0', '-')-1) as signed) >= 3 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                               1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`unsigned` would probably be better for readability. wouldn't likely have any affect on the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from main where cast(split_str(experience, '-', 1) as unsigned) >= 3;
```

split_str (it is an user function : http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/, not by default in mysql) will split your column with its seperator and cast will turn your string into an int unsigned, then you can test it.
Else if one day you want to test months and years, like all experience above 3 year and 10 months, you can convert your value in decimal (this also work for above test) :

```
Select * from main where cast(replace(experience, '-', '.') As decimal(5,2)) > 3.10;
```

I might have done some typos (typing on my smartphone), but you have got the idea.

Comment: i am using mysql 5.6, this query not supports for this version server.

Comment: My bad the first one is an user functiin (split_str) I have at work and forgot it was not by default, you can find it it here if interested : http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Comment: yes i cheched secound query, decimal function not present in mysql 5.6 version. shows 1064 error.

Comment: I corrected the second request, correct syntax for cast is : cast(columnname AS datatype) and not «,». I was mistaking with convert syntax. Decimal data type is recognized by mysql 5.6

Comment: supports upto 9 years i am not able to get `>10` or `>11`;

Comment: Well decimal(3,2) allows up to 999.99 so 999years, it should be working. Can you write the result of your +10 years experience rows with this request : select cast(replace(experience,  '-', '.') as decimal(3,2)), replace(experience,  '-', '.'), experience from main; so I can see what is wrong.

Comment: Ok i got it my decimal conversion was just wrong, first digit is number total of digit not number to the left. So 5,2 will allow 999.99 as max, 3,2 only allows 9.99. Sorry for this blame it on the stuffed xmas turkey !

Comment: So this solution should allows you to test years of experience but also years and months.

Answer (score 0):

how about strcmp for this simple case? it wouldn't work if you needed both year and month though.

```
mysql> select strcmp('3-','3-1');
+--------------------+
| strcmp('3-','3-1') |
+--------------------+
|                 -1 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select strcmp('3-','3-9');
+--------------------+
| strcmp('3-','3-9') |
+--------------------+
|                 -1 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select strcmp('3-','2-9');
+--------------------+
| strcmp('3-','2-9') |
+--------------------+
|                  1 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

you use this in a query like so:

```
mysql> select * from main where strcmp('ab', url) = 1;
+----+---------------+
| id | url           |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | a.com         |
|  2 | aa.com        |
|  3 | aaa.com       |
|  4 | aachen.com    |
|  5 | aah.com       |
|  6 | aaliyah.com   |
|  7 | aaliyahs.com  |
|  8 | aardvark.com  |
|  9 | aardvarks.com |
| 10 | aaron.com     |
| 11 | aas.com       |
+----+---------------+
11 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

so in your case you'd want something like `select * from employee where strcmp('3-', experience) = -1;`

if I were the db admin, and if the `experience` mentioned means years at this job, I'd be wishing I had just used timestamps for start and end, so it could easily be calculated. otherwise every month a batch job will have to update the field.

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp

[UPDATE: fixed for cases from 11- to 29-, by checking if the years part of the string is greater than a single digit]

`select * from employee where strcmp('3-', experience) = -1 or instr(experience, '-') > 2;`

Comment: `mysql> select strcmp('3-','7-9')` shows `-1` what it means?

Comment: it means '7-9' is greater than '3-'; well to be specific, it means '3-' is less than '7-9'.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp

Comment: fixed for broken cases, it will still break for people on the job for 100 years or more.

Comment: Hmm.. i did not get records who has more than 10 and 10+ years experience, it supports upto 9 years. plus i tried ur updated query also.

Comment: I had reversed the test. fixed now [hopefully]